# How to do in this in Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

So far, I have this:

```
var v = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_strConfigurationFolder)
    .GroupBy(x => GetReportName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)));
```

Configuration folder will contain pairs of files:

```
abc.json
abc-input.json
def.json
def-input.json
```

GetReportName() method strips off the "-input" and title cases the filename, so you end up with a grouping of:

```
Abc
 abc.json
 abc-input.json
Def
 def.json
 def-input.json
```

I have a ReportItem class that has a constructor (Name, str1, str2). I want to extend the Linq to create the ReportItems in a single statement, so really something like:

```
var v = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_strConfigurationFolder)
                     .GroupBy(x => GetReportName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)))
**.Select(x => new ReportItem(x.Key, x[0], x[1]));**
```

Obviously last line doesn't work because the grouping doesn't support array indexing like that. The item should be constructed as "Abc", "abc.json", "abc-input.json", etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that each group of interest contains exactly two items, use `First()` to get the item at index 0, and `Last()` to get the item at index 1:

```
var v = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_strConfigurationFolder)
    .GroupBy(x => GetReportName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)))
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 2) // Make sure we have exactly two items
    .Select(x => new ReportItem(x.Key, x.First(), x.Last()));
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Had to add in a OrderBy to get the -input files to appear in a consistent order relative to the grouping.

Comment: If you are certain that you only want the first two elements of each group, then First() and Last() will be significantly slower than using Take(2).ToArray()  per group and then take [0] and [1].

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse You don't need `Take(2)`, because `Where` clause ensures that each group has exactly two elements.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice the Where. Still it's not wise to use First and Last, because the enumeration will start twice, while ToList() will make sure the enumeration is only done once.

Answer (score 3):

```
var v = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_strConfigurationFolder)
                     .GroupBy(x => GetReportName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x))).Select(x => new ReportItem(x.Key, x.FirstOrDefault(), x.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()));
```

But are you sure there will be exactly two items in each group? Maybe has it sence for ReportItem to accept IEnumerable, not just two strings?